# encrypt text Could someone please show me how to do this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've written a program that reads and prints text files that the user has chosen. I now want the program to encrypt the text in the file and for the user be able to choose the alphabetic shift. Could someone please show me how to do this? Here is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *file_in;
    char filename[20];
    char ch;
    int shift;
    // file_in is the name given to the stream. filename will be the file that the user chooses. ch is the characters in the file.


    printf("What file do you want to open?: ");
    gets(filename);
    file_in=fopen(filename, "r");
    //ask the user to enter the name of a file

    if(file_in==NULL)
        printf("Error! File did not open.\n");
    //print message if the file can not be found

    while((ch=fgetc(file_in)) != EOF) 
        putchar(ch);
        //prints the results on the screen and shows the end of the file
    fclose(file_in);
    //closes stream
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: Generally speaking, **do not** write encryption code yourself, other than as a programming exercise. Rely on well-tested, open-sourced code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple alphabetic shift store the shift as an `char` and read it just like the filename from userinput. Replace `putchar(ch);` by `putchar(ch+shift);` for encryption and `ch-shift` for decryption or vv. `ch+shift` will silently overflow if the sum is larger than the maximal value for a `char` and thus guarantee that every letter `ch` has exactly one "encrypted" correspondant.